# Convergence of $\sum \frac {1}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say you have series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

I have conventionally seen convergence of this proved using comparison tests involving the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$ which is of course larger than $1/n^2$.

However, say I was to use $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
Can we adjust $n(n+1)$ to function in the same way as $n(n-1)$ for the purposes of evaluating $1/n^2$.

(In other words, can I prove the convergence of series $1/n^2$ using series $1/n(n+1)$ as defined above)

I have tried the comparison tests and am aware that $1/n(n+1)$ does converge. In doing this proof, I'm trying to better understand the comparison of series.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *limit comparison test* states that if $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are sequences with positive terms and $$0 < \lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} < \infty$$ then the series $$\sum_n a_n\qquad \sum_n b_n$$ either both converge or both diverge.

In your case $$\frac{\dfrac 1{n^2}}{\dfrac 1{n(n+1)}} = \frac{n^2 + n}{n^2} \to 1.$$ Since one series converges so does the other.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

and $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$

are, in fact, the exact same series, as all of their summands match exactly.

---

In particular,

- the $k$-th summand of the first series is reached when $n=k$, and the summand is equal to $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$
- the $k$-th summand of the second series is reached when $n=k+1$, and the summand is equal to $\frac{1}{(k+1)((k+1)-1)}=\frac{1}{(k+1)k}$.